# How to remove bracketed sections of a Url

Tags: c#, regex, url

In my c# application I am building a routine that will parse through a url replace any sections of the url with the appropriate data.

For instance, if I have a url like:

`api.domain.com/users/{id}`

and the user provides the id, i replace the id with the given value.

This is simple enough:

`if(path.Contains("{id}") path = path.Replace("{id}", id);`

However, what I want is to be able to remove the `{id}` from the url if no id is provided so that the final url is:
`api.domain.com/users`

I would also want it to intelligently be able to remove items in the middle of the path so that if the url were:
`api.domain.com/users/{id}/photos`

I would get: 
`api.domain.com/users/photos`

For this, I would not know the text of the key ahead of time so `{id}` could be anything such as:

`{name} {sometext} {anyvalue}`

But I do know that each MUST be contained in curly braces.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can adjust to use {0} and replace with string.Format() ?

Comment: What have you attempted to complete this so far? Can you post this " I am building a routine that will parse through a url replace any sections"

Comment: 2 points: 1. `if(path.Contains("{id}") path = path.Replace("{id}", id)` - you don't need the contains check. You can just do `.Replace()` and it will only replace it if it actually exists. 2.Why can't you just always use the replace for the middle? The URL will still work even if there is a double slash.

Comment: @TotZam For 2, I do not actually know ahead of time what text is between the brackets to do a replace.

Comment: Are you on purpose not using RouteConfig because it seems like you are basically doing that manually? ex: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public string UrlReplace(string Url, string key, string value = "")
{
    var replaceString = "{" + key + "}"; //get the string to replace

    //if the value is empty remove the slash
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        //find the index of the replace string in the url
        var index = url.IndexOf(replaceString) + replaceString.Length;
        if (url[index] == '/')
        {
            url = url.Remove(index, 1); //if the character after the string is a slash, remove it
        }
    }
    return url.Replace(replaceString, value);  //replace the string with the value
}
```

Then you'd use it like

```
string url = "api.domain.com/users/{id}/photos";
url = UrlReplace(url,"id","test");
//returns "api.domain.com/users/test/photos"
url = UrlReplace(url, "id", "");
//returns "api.domain.com/users/photos"
```